# Multiply the object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

someone tell me how to multiply object's properties? I need this object multiplied by the count of property price and put together

```
var menu = [  
       {  
          "id": 5,
          "price": 13,
          "count": 2
       },
       {  
          "id": 8,
          "price": 7,
          "count": 3
       },
       {
            "id": 9,
            "price": 17,
            "count": 1
       }
    ]

var sum = 0;
for (var key in menu) {
    for (var key1 in menu[key]) {
        //console.log(key1);
        if (key1 == 'price'){
            price += menu[key][key1];
        }

    }

}
```

but I have no idea how to multiply count property

Comment: show us something that you have tried?

Comment: At least show us the expected result.

Comment: you want the sum of all `price * count` ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

suppose you want to calculate the sum

```js
var menu = [
    {
    "id": 5, "price": 13, "count": 2 }, {
    "id": 8, "price": 7, "count": 3 }, { "id": 9, "price": 17, "count": 1 } ];
    var sum = 0, item;
    for(item in menu)
    {
      sum += menu[item].price * menu[item].count;
    }
    console.log(sum);
```

Comment: @JohnDoe is this you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

`.map` takes a callback function which will multiply the *price* of each item by the *count* and creates a new `array` looking like this:

`[26,21,17]`.

`.reduce` takes a callback as well, iterating over the new create array summing up the multiplied prices resulting to:

`64`

```js
let menu = [  
  {  
    "id": 5,
    "price": 13,
    "count": 2
  },
  {  
    "id": 8,
    "price": 7,
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "price": 17,
    "count": 1
  }
]


let sum = menu.map(p => p.price * p.count).reduce((a,b) => a + b)

console.log("Total:",sum)
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want something like this:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "price": 13,
    "count": 3,
    "value": function() {return this.price * this.count;}
}
```

You can do that by either making an object and adding a prototype (which saves memory and time) or construct it that way each time.

Otherwise you can just do:

```
var obj = { ... } // your stuff
alert(obj.price * obj.count)
```